# Magic 8ball Using securerandom with switch statements and while loops

Tags: java, random, while-loop, switch-statement, secure-random

I have my following code working like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Magiceightball {
private static void Number() {
    int magic = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    String x;
    switch (magic)
    {
        case 1: x = "Yes.";
        break;
        case 2: x = "No.";
        break;
        case 3: x = "The odds are in favor.";
        break;
        case 4: x = "The odds are against you.";
        break;
        case 5: x = "Never.";
        break;
        case 6: x = "Definitely!";
        break;
        case 7: x = "Maybe.";
        break;
        case 8: x = "I don't think so.";
        break;
        case 9: x = "I'd say no.";
        break;
        case 10: x = "Probably.";
        break;

        default: x = "Try Again.";
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}

public static void main (String [ ] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean a = true;

    while (a)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("What would you like to ask the Magic Eight Ball? Make it a \"Yes\" or \"No\" question for it to work.");
        System.out.print("\n\n--> ");
        String what = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        Number();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();            
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to go again? Enter \"Y\" for yes, and \"N\" for no.");

        System.out.print("\n\n--> ");
        String run = scan.nextLine();
        run = run.toLowerCase();

        if (run.equals("n"))
        {
            a = false;
        }
    }
}
```

} `

My dilemma is, I want all these methods being used the switch statement, the while loop but I want to replace the Math.random with the SecureRandom method how would I go about doing that?

I tried using the whole SecureRandom randomNumber = new SecureRandom(); to do it but it kept giving me errors that I could not convert secure random to "int".

Comment: **Secure** random for a simple game? Sure, ok, but a bit of overkill. Just use a normal `Random`. --- *"but it kept giving me errors"* How about you actually show us the code that give you errors, then maybe we can help you figure out what you did wrong. You did remember to call one of the `getInt()` methods on the `Random` object, right?

Comment: An array or a list would be substantially easier than a switch: `String x = Arrays.asList("Yes.", "No." /* etc */).get(magic);`.

Comment: @Andreas this is part of an assignment where i have to use the .securerandom method, with the while and switch.  So its mandatory to get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to instantiate a `SecureRandom` object and use its `nextInt()` method:

```
Random rand = new SecureRandom();
int magic = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: Ok i must not be doing something right, how would i include that in my code?  Just replace "int magic = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);" with what you wrote?

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi yup, exactly

Comment: Never mind, got it working thanks!  it was suppose to be SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public static int generateRandomInteger(int min, int max) {
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Call it with

```
int magic = generateRandomInteger(1,10); // to get a number between 1 and 10.
```